# Circle drawn on canvas doesn't match the screen

Tags: android, graphics, canvas

I want to draw circle in center of screen, but I'm getting something like this:

[image]

I'm using this code to draw this circle.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

    RectF rect = new RectF(0,0,width,width);
    drawCircle(rect, c, width, height);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);


}

private void drawCircle(RectF rect, Canvas c, int width, int height) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(255, 255 , 10, 21);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    int radius;
    if(width < height)
        radius = width/2;
    else 
        radius = height/2;
    c.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, paint);
}
```

I don't understand why it's cut at sides even though I use size of screen to draw it, so it should perfectly fit it.

Comment: you didn't account for the thickness of the line. you drew a circle assuming it had 0 thickness, so the "actual" circle **IS** touching the edges of the screen, but since you used a thick paintbrush, some of the pain leaked past the edge.

Comment: Shouldn't you consider also the strokeWidth

Comment: @MarcB I think you should actually post it as answer :-)

Comment: @MarcB Yes, you're right. I feel so ashamed I didn't think about it.

Comment: A tip: don't use ARGB_4444, use ARGB_8888 instead,  besides that just use width/height-5(or a bit more)/2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't account for the thickness of the line (strokeWidth). You drew a circle assuming it had 0 thickness, so the "actual" circle IS touching the edges of the screen, but since you used a thick paintbrush, some of the paint leaked past the edge.

Answer (score 2):

you should decrease the thickness/2.

```
    private void drawCircle(RectF rect, Canvas c, int width, int height) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(255, 255 , 10, 21);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int radius;
        if(width < height)
            radius = width/2;
        else 
            radius = height/2;

//this is the new line:
        radius-= 5;
        c.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, paint);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Account for the `StrokeWidth` in the radius:

```
// Substract stroke width.
radius -= paint.getStrokeWidth() / 2;
c.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, paint);
```