# Coordinates not corresponding

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I'm pretty new to Android and I'm really struggling trying to understand what is going on in my application. 
I'm trying to build a small game in which a circle appears on the screen, in a random position and it disappears as soon as the user clicks on it. Then a new circle appears in another position.

The problem is that comparing the coordinates of the user's click, and the coordinates of the center of the circle, these seem to be totally different…
The problem seems to be in the circle coordinates, because if I try to force its position to the center of the view, it appears in a totally wrong position, at the right bottom of the view.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code of the function drawing the circles in the view (which is as big as its parent).

```
public void drawDots(){
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    View ll = (View) findViewById(R.id.circle);
    ll.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

    centerX = rand.nextInt(ll.getWidth());
    centerY = rand.nextInt(ll.getHeight());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);
    Log.i("Point center X :" + centerX, " Y " + centerY);

    ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                Log.i("CLICK X: " + x, "click Y: " + y);

                if((x < (centerX + radius) && x > (centerX - radius))) && ((y > centerY + radius) && (y < centerY - radius)) ){
                    Log.i("x ok: " + x + " y  ok: " + y, "Counter: " + counter);
                    drawDots();

                }else{
                    Log.i("x NOT ok " + x,  " Circle area between: " + (centerX-radius) + " e " + (centerX + radius));
                    Log.i("Y NOT ok " + y,  " Circle area between: " + (centerY-radius) + " e " + (centerY + radius));
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the layout. The textview and the button are needed to start a timer but they are removed from the layout as soon as the user clicks on the start button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/timerVal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:text="@string/startButtonLabel" />

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/circle"/>
```

Sorry for my bad explanation but I even dunno where the problem is.

**EDIT** I tried this solution and it actually seems to improve the situation but if i only consider the x-axis, for the y-axis there is any  correspondence but in this way it seems the coordinates of the click are totally out of range... [Circle drawn on canvas doesn't match the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217567/circle-drawn-on-canvas-doesnt-match-the-screen)

even though i actually don't understand WHY it is needed

Comment: can you post a layout also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, which was here:

```
Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

with this call i was specifying a view of 480px of width and 800px of height, whereas my view is occupying the entire parent view (which is the screen).
This was a quite a newbie mistake, but i hope it could help someone else as i've been struggling for two days with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> centerX = rand.nextInt(ll.getWidth());

`ll.getWidth()` returns you `0` and `rand.nextInt()` won't work 
when `ll.getWidth()` is `0`.

so cannot call `nextInt(0)`.  Check out [Random#nextInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29).

---

to fix this make a check:

```
if(ll.getWidth() == 0)
   centerX = 0;
else
   centerX = rand.nextInt(ll.getWidth());
```

But I'm not certain what you are doing so hopefully you will find a better solution.

> P.S -  same you have to do with the other case, I still doubt what is the need of `rand.nextInt(ll.getWidth());`. (you may edit your question and make clear what you want to achieve)

*as a newbie you code is nice enough to gain upvotes* :)

~happycoding

Comment: Thanx for your reply and for the compliments for the code. Actually i "cleaned" it from useless logging for debugging and I checked that ll.getWidth() returns me  a proper value (meaning it returns 656, as the screenwidth of my phone is 720; for the height it returns 1070 and the total height of the screen is 1280. ll.getX and ll.getY return both 32 so it seems ok for the width but not so much for the height... even if i think it could be the space of the activity bar).

Comment: i thought i wrote it in the question: i need a random position for the circle, that's for what the rand.nextInt is needed. to change the center of the circle to any new circle... not clear enough? should i better explain it?